# Does this class of triangles satisfy a certain geometric inequality?

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

If $\Delta{}ABC$ is a triangle, call the segment perpendicular to $AB$ and containing $C$ the *altitude segment at* $C$. In brief my question is the following: is it true that for all $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and all triangles $\Delta{}ABC$ satisfying $\measuredangle{}ACB=\theta$, there exists a point $P$ on the altitude segment at $C$ such that $PA+PB+PC<AC+BC$? See the figure below for an example.

[image]

Now for some context: I have read in *The Secrets of Triangles: A Mathematical Journey* by Alfred S. Posamentier and Ingmar Lehmann that if $AB$ is the shortest side of triangle $\Delta{}ABC$ and $P$ is any point in the interior of $\Delta{}ABC$, then $PA+PB+PC<AC+BC$. (The "proof" they give seems rather incomplete.)

While playing with the geometry of the points $A,B,C,P$, I noticed that for many triangles that do not satisfy the condition that $AB$ be the shortest edge of the triangle $\Delta{}ABC$, there nonetheless often *exists* a point $P$ in the interior of $\Delta{}ABC$ (and especially on the altitude segment at $C$) such that $PA+PB+PC<AC+BC$.

For certain reasons, I am interested in (and am restricting to) the case when $0<\measuredangle{}ACB<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $P$ is required to lie on the altitude segment at $C$. Is one always guaranteed the existence of such a point $P$ satisfying $PA+PB+PC<AC+BC$ whenever $0<\measuredangle{}ACB<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

**Addition:** Is it any easier under the further assumption that $\Delta{}ABC$ be acute? This assumption guarantees that the orthocenter lie in the interior of $\Delta{}ABC$. I am quite interested in this sub-case.

Comment: The following may be useful. We can first prove the following inequality: $\sin A+\sin B>\cos A+\cos B+\cos C$. Then, multiplying both sides by $2R$, where $R$ denotes the circumradius yields $BC+AC<HA+HB+HC$, where $H$ denotes the orthocenter.

Comment: @dodoturkoz It seems plausible that the orthocenter always satisfies the property of interest—I am unable to find an example where it does not. Are you able to fill in any of the details that would lead to a proof of this (ideally in the form of an answer)? Thanks!

Comment: @dodoturkoz: You should expand your comment as an answer to [OP's follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4212853/409).

Answer (score 1):

If $AB\leq AC$ and $AB\leq BC$ so it's true for any point $P$ inside the triangle.

I hope at least this fact would be completed.

Indeed, let $D\in AC$, $E\in BC$, $P\in DE$ such that $DE||AB$ and $CE=kBC$.

Thus, $CD=kAC$ and by the triangle inequality we obtain:
$$PA+PB+PC<AD+DP+BE+EP+PC=AD+BE+DE+PC=$$
$$=(1-k)AC+(1-k)BC+kAB+PC<$$
$$<(1-k)AC+(1-k)BC+kAB+\max\{DC,EC\}=$$
$$=(1-k)AC+(1-k)BC+kAB+k\max\{AC,BC\}=$$
$$=AC+BC+k\left(AB-AC-BC+\max\{AC,BC\}\right)\leq AC+BC.$$

Comment: This certainly fills in the details that are missing in Posamentier and Lehmann's book. Thanks! Perhaps similar reasoning can be used to handle the more general cases? I am also interested in the sub-case when $\Delta{}ABC$ is acute.

Comment: In fact the conditions are necessary, in right triangle $ABC$ in $C$ the altitude from $C$ of length $h_C$ verifies $h_C+BA> AC+CB$ you can see a proof in french here http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?8,2228908,2230734#msg-2230734