# Does the orthocenter of an acute triangle satisfy this inequality?

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $\Delta{}ABC$ be an acute triangle and $O$ its orthocenter, so that $O$ is in the interior of $\Delta{}ABC$. Is it true that $OA+OB+OC$ is less than the sum of any two sides of $\Delta{}ABC$? In other words, do all of the following necessarily hold:

1. $OA+OB+OC<AB+AC$
2. $OA+OB+OC<AB+BC$
3. $OA+OB+OC<AC+BC$?

This question grew out of [my previous SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212381/does-this-class-of-triangles-satisfy-a-certain-geometric-inequality) that asks about a more general scenario where we only assume that $0<\measuredangle{}ACB<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and seek a point $P$ on the altitude from $C$ that satisfies the inequality $PA+PB+PC<AC+BC$. Restricting to acute triangles and the orthocenter, as this question does, seems interesting and specific enough to warrant its own question.

Comment: Yes it does. In fact, it holds true for an aribtrary interior point, not just the orthocenter of an acute triangle. In that general context, you should be able to find reference for proofs.

Comment: @CalvinLin I do not think this is true. Consider the triangle with vertices (0.4, 0.6), (1, 0), (0.4, -0.4). The point (0.41, 0) is interior to the triangle but does not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: K, reading it, it requires that if $AB$ is the shortest side of the triangle, then for an interior point $P$, $PA+PB+PC \leq AC + BC$ with equality iff $ P = C$.

Comment: Please avoid "do my homework for me"-style questions. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @user1729 I completely agree with the fact that the question lacks context, but I believe it is in response to my comment on OP's previous post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4212381/does-this-class-of-triangles-satisfy-a-certain-geometric-inequality

Comment: @dodoturkoz That's fine context, but then they should edit something in to say this.

Comment: @user1729 I have now included context in the question body. Please consider opening the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Credit to @VMF-er](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2282985p17897851)

---

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of the acute-angled $\triangle ABC$ ($H$ is traditionally more commonly used).

Let $E \in AB$ and $F \in AC$ such that $\angle{BHE}=\angle{CHF}=90°$.

Observe that $AEHF$ is a parallelogram:

$$AE+AF>HA$$

Further, $\triangle BEH$ and $\triangle CFH$ are right triangles:

$$BE>HB \;\;\text{and}\;\; CF>HC$$

Adding the three inequalities, we get the desired inequality:

$$HA+HB+HC<AB+AC$$

Applying this cyclically proves the problem. $\;\blacksquare$

---

In fact, the following is a corollary of this result (using the extended law of sines and $AH=2R\cos(A$)...:

$$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C<\sin B+\sin C$$

We could also reverse-engineer and use this trigonometric inequality as our starting point, but that would require using sum to product formulae and an analysis of increasing/decreasing behaviour on certain domains, etc. which seems like a clumsier solution.

Comment: This is a neat and simple proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Let the foots of altitudes on sides BC=a, AC=b and AB=c be D, F and E and altitudes be $h_a$, $h_b$ and $h_c$ respectively. Use this fact:

$h_a+h_b+h_c< a+ b+ c$

Or:

$(OA+ OD)+(OB+OE)+(OC+OF)<a+b+c$

For example move $a$ to LHS:

$OA+OB+OC+[(OE+OF+OD)-a]<a+b$

Now you have to show $(OE+OF+OD)-a\geq 0$

It is obvious for condition $a<b<c$ for biggest side c you may need some calculation to show that.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I believe this can be used to show that $OA+OB+OC$ is less than the sum of the two longest sides of $\Delta{}ABC$. But it is not true in general that $(OD+OE+OF)-s\geq0$ if $s$ is allowed to be any side of $\Delta{}ABC$ (it is easy to construct an example, letting $s$ be the longest side of $\Delta{}ABC$).

Answer (score 0):

Using more traditional $H$ for the orthocenter and $O$ for the circumcenter.

[image]

Let $\rho,r$ and $R$ denote the semiperimeter, inradius and circumradius of the triangle, respectively
and WLOG let $c$ be the longest side of the triangle.

Hint: for acute triangles
\begin{align}
|AH|+|BH|+|CH|&=2(r+R)
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Hence it's suffice to show that
\begin{align}
2(r+R)&<a+b
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
2(r+R)&<2\rho-c
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
c&<2\rho-2(r+R)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
\frac cR&<2\frac\rho{R}-2\frac rR-2
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

For acute triangles
we have $\tfrac cR<2$
and
$\tfrac\rho{R}>\tfrac rR+2$,
that is
\begin{align}
2\frac\rho{R}-2\frac rR-2
&>2
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}
hence \eqref{5} is true.

Comment: The logic here seems correct. Would it be possible for you to provide references for equation (1) and the inequalities $\frac{c}{R}<2$ and $\frac{\rho}{R}>\frac{r}{R}+2$ concerning acute triangles? Thank you!

Comment: @ Sam van der Poel: For $|AH|+|BH|+|CH|=2r+2R$
see [Other excircle properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Other_excircle_properties).
For the other two consider acute triangle inscribed into unit circle.

Comment: I found/understand the first two but I am unable to see why acute triangles satisfy $\frac{\rho}{R}>\frac{r}{R}+2$. The associated [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles#Circumradius,_inradius,_and_exradii) references only a statement of the result from *Crux Mathematicorum*. Could you explain why this inequality is true or refer me to a proof? Thanks.

Comment: @Sam van der Poel: Consider WLOG $R=1$.
That's a well-known property: $\rho=r+2$ for right-angled triangles,
$\rho>r+2$ for acute 
and $\rho<r+2$ for obtuse triangles. It's based on 
$a^2+b^2\lesseqqgtr c^2$.